# Which cameras have built-in HDR?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, hdr, features

When taking landscape photos, I often struggle with dynamic range. I have either a burned out skies or landscapes are too dark.

Now I'm reading [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autobracketing) that some cameras can take 3 pictures with different exposures, and combine them automatically to one image with higher dynamic range.

So my question is, which cameras have this feature?

Comment: If you are looking for a camera that combines the exposures automatically, you are looking for HDR mode - not Exposure Bracketing. Exposure bracketing will leave you with 3 pictures that you would need to combine yourself on the computer.

Comment: thanks for clarifying camflan. had no clue this was HDR, always thought HDR was about weird color effects

Comment: HDR gets a bad rap because 90% of the time, it's overdone. You'll also get the halos around objects from older software or poor post-processing techniques. The key is to use HDR subtly.

Comment: This question asks for a list of cameras. In the four years since then, the answers have not been kept up to date. Let's put it out of its misery...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as DSLRs go, the Pentax K-5, K-7, most of the Sony Alphas, the newer Nikons as well as the newer Canons like the 5D-Mark III, 650D, and newly announced 6D all have HDR built-into the camera. In addition to DSLRs, a lot of point and shoot, micro 4/3s and mirrorless cameras also come with this.

For your purposes, it seems as though the Sony NEX cameras should be at the top of your list. They are equipped with large APS-C sensors and tons of in-camera processing tricks - both HDR and Sweep-Panoramas.

#### DSLRs

- Pentax K-5
- Pentax K-7
- Canon 650D
- Canon 5D III
- Canon 6D
- Nikon 5100/5200
- Nikon 7100
- Nikon D600
- Nikon D800
- Nikon D4
- Sony SLT-A99
- Sony SLT-A77
- Sony SLT-A55/A57
- Sony SLT-A35/37

#### Mirrorless / ILC (no viewfinder)

- Sony NEX-3
- Sony NEX-5 / 5N / 5R
- Sony NEX-6
- Sony NEX-7
- Nikon 1 J2 ([on back-light mode](http://imaging.nikon.com/lineup/acil/bodies/j2/features02.htm))

#### Compact / Point & Shoot

- Olympus XZ-2
- Panasonic Lumix ZS20

Comment: 650D reportedly also has HDR

Comment: Please edit to present the answers in a "list like" style, to help increase reading speed. Thanks.

Comment: I've just read that the Olympus XZ-2 has HDR mode too. It's a compact camera.

Comment: @camflan Nikon D5100 also has HDR. It is build in HDR mode but it also has bracketed mode.

Comment: All of Sony's Alpha SLT line has built in HDR functionality. Though I've had better luck using software on my computer to combine bracketed images in to an HDR image.

Answer (score 5):

There are few options if you want to improve burned out skies on your pictures.

Most of DSLR can have bracketing option that you can set on the camera. Some can do about 3 pictures bracketing. One with normal exposure, one with lower exposure and one with higher exposure. You can usually set increment value for lower and higher exposure. More advanced DSLR which are normally full frame pro camera can do about 7 or 9 bracketed shots. For this option you normally need a tripod and do some post production to combine your shots in a software like Photoshop.

Newer cameras such as Nikon D600, D800, Canon 5DMark III and 650D(not sure) have built-in HDR function. I have tested on 5DMark III and it is awesome. The dynamic range is much improved and the images do not feel surreal.

Another option is to use 'ND Grad' filter. There are a lot of filters out there that you can use for your landscape. Cokin P is normally to start with but I use Lee filter but those are normally expensive. Hitech filters are reasonably priced and very good quality too.

Comment: Correct exposure measurement and shooting raw might also help.

Comment: I will add that in the D800, so probably most others, the in-camera HDR only works when shooting to jpg, not RAW.

Comment: Yeap .. I always shot RAW (apart from wedding where you find number of pictures in a day would close to a thousand) before HDR mode available to cameras. Well, I still shoot RAW for 95% of shots. Cheers guys !

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand - in-camera HDR should generally be avoided as it is very limited in ability.  For my money (and it is my money as I have invested!) shooting RAW and getting yourself a copy of Photomatix Pro would be a much better way to create HDR's.  Also the latest Photoshop can merge RAW's into HDR, but again with less control than a dedicated app like Photomatix.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that all modern dslr cameras can do automatic bracketing. http://www.pointsinfocus.com/learning/cameras-lenses/guide-to-auto-exposure-bracketing-on-canon-dslrs/ tells you how to do it with canon cameras.